# Not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

I have updated today my build.gradle file to the latest version
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3' and the latest ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72' 
and I get the following error that is in the title at: instance().

```
private val viewModelFactory: ListViewModelFactory by instance()
```

This is my Factory class:

```
class ListViewModelFactory(
    private val listRepository: ListRepository
) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return ListViewModel(listRepository) as T
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this occurred and how can I get rid of the error. Thank you in advance!

P.S. if it is of any help I use kodein and here is my bind

```
bind() from provider { ListViewModelFactory(instance()) }
```

Comment: `ListViewModelFactory` remains a template with unspecified T parameter because it inherits from `ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory`. Try `ListViewModelFactory<MyTClass>(instance())`.

Comment: It doesn't work it says: No type arguments expected for constructor ListViewModelFactory(listRepository:ListRepository) and by instance() it says now Property getter or setter expected.

Comment: Post your ViewModel class as well.

Comment: Here it is: `class ListViewModel(
    private val listRepository: ListRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val list : Deferred<LiveData<out List<ListItemEntity>>> by lazyDeferred {
        listRepository.getList()
    }
    fun upsertItem(item: ListItemEntity) {
        listRepository.upsertItem(item)
    }
    fun deleteItem(item: ListItemEntity) {
        listRepository.deleteItem(item)
    }
}` Thank you for the response @BelalKhan  hope this helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

can you try 
`private val viewModelFactory by instance<ListViewModelFactory>()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :  Replace

```
 private val factory : AuthViewModelFactory by instance()
```

to

```
  private val factory by instance<AuthViewModelFactory>()
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the problem please disable the new type inference in "Preferences | Kotlin Compiler" in the IDE.